# Why is my regular Expression that ignore the order of the characters does not work?

Tags: regex, expression

I want to make a string pattern that is:

1. at least 7 characters long
2. have at least 1 digits, max 5
3. have at least 3 capital alphabetic characters , max 5
4. have at least 1 lower alphabetic characters , max 5
5. have at least 1 special  characters , max 5

How to express this in a regular expression?
I can do something like

```
^((?=.*[A-Z]{3,5})(?=.*[a-z]{1,5})(?=.*[0-9]{1,5})(?=.*[.~!@#$%^_&-]{1,5}))(?=.{7,20}).*$
```

I don't want to require this kind of order. In fact, any mixed order should be accepted, only require the number of characters.

This Match:

```
PASSW120P45ccb^&@%#
```

But this one does not

```
PA12S1SW2045ccb^&@%#
```

How can i fix this?

```
P&@Ass120W45ccb^%#
P&@Ass20W45cb^%#
```

Please have a look at https://regex101.com/r/vF2yO7/51

Answer (score 1):

You need to operate with the contrary character classes, put these into non-capturing groups and repeat **these**:

```
^
(?=(?:\D*\d){1,5})
(?=(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){3,5})
(?=(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){1,5})
(?=(?:[^.\~!@#$%^_&-]*[.\~!@#$%^_&-]){1,5})
.{7,20}
$
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/vF2yO7/52).

---

The structure here is always the same, e.g. with the numbers: require anything *not* a number zero or more times, followed by a number and repeat the whole pattern 1-5 times. In general:

```
(?=(?:not_what_you_want*what_you_want){min_times, max_times})
```

In the expression above, all pos. lookaheads follow this scheme, `[^...]` negates the characters to be matched in the class and `\D*` is essentially the same as `[^\d]*`.